# Liquibase, postgresql в проекте

Tags: sql, postgresql

файл learndb.sql

```
    CREATE TABLE learndb(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    valueRU varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    valueKK varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    valueEN varchar(255) NOT NULL
)



  - changeSet:
      id: 19
      author: vasya
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            path: learndb.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
            splitStatements: false
```

ChangeSet в ChangeLog(e). Где я указываю путь к файлу. 
1 Вопрос: Почему-то в файле learndb.sql не подсвечивает никак `AUTO_INCREMENT` как будто не работает/не используется. Вообще работал в postgres, создал бд и там создавал таблицы и работал с запросами в psql консоли. А тут в проекте Liquibase, где нужно в ченджлоге написать ченджсет и прописать путь к файлу и потом запустить что ли? Просто разбираюсь сижу, подскажите люди добрые))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В postgresql на самом деле нет синтаксиса `AUTO_INCREMENT` и ваш `create table` в postgresql вызовет ошибку синтаксиса. Это ключевое слово на сколько знаю только в `mysql` используется.

В postgresql существуют отдельные объекты `sequence`, живущие независимо от таблицы и отдельно же создаваемые. Так же есть псевдотипы `serial`/`bigserial` для синтаксический сахар вокруг `sequence`, часто используется этот вариант:

```
CREATE TABLE learndb(
    ID serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    valueRU varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    valueKK varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    valueEN varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Либо начиная с postgresql 10 стал доступен синтаксис из современного стандарта SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE learndb(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    valueRU varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    valueKK varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    valueEN varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Под капотом, впрочем, это всё равно тот же самый `sequence`

Comment: GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY это что? Понимаю что могу загуглить, но хочу более легкую и понятную информацию услышать, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как уже упомянул - это синтаксис объявления колонки автогенерации значений из современного стандарта SQL. Для тех же целей что в своё время изобрели sequence и serial в postgresql, auto_increment в mysql и другие свои реализации в других базах. Потому что в стандарте ничего подходящего не было. Затем это появилось в стандарте.